# How to fit image as background cover in a div in tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css

How to fit image as background cover in a div in tailwind css. The top portion of image is cutting in desktop view and mobile view is extending the image a bit to both sides. How can i fix this ?

```
         <div class="relative">
            <div class="w-full h-[450px] bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-cover bg-life-easier">
                <div class="relative inset-0 flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-white">
                    <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold mt-2">We makes your life easier.</h1>
                    <p class="text-lg">Our deligent services!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'life-easier': "url('../public/images/hometopImg.png')",
      },
    },
  },
```

See the top part of the image is not seen..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set vertical backgroundposition to 0 percent to force image start on top.

```
  theme: {
      extend: {
          backgroundImage: {
              'life-easier': "url('../public/images/hometopImg.png')",
          },
          backgroundPosition: {
              'life-easier': '50% 0%',
          },
      },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add object fit: cover.

```
<div class="relative">
        <div class="w-full h-[450px] bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-cover bg-life-easier object-cover">
                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
            <div class="relative inset-0 flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-white">
                <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold mt-2">We makes your life easier.</h1>
                <p class="text-lg">Our deligent services!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

According to https://tailwindcss.com/docs/object-fit

Comment: Sorry i doesn't make much difference. If I increase `h-[450px] ` only i can see the image in full view, but i dont want to increase the height more that 450px

Comment: Check the link and try other object-fit types too. I might understood you wrong.

Comment: I have tried most of the object fit types, I have added the look of the image as screenshot.